# Adal.NET acquiretoken for current application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, jwt, adal

Is it possible to acquire a jwt token for the current application and not based on another Azure app or keep it through the entire lifecycle of signed in?

In my app I'm authenticating my user to Azure with Owin and OpenIdConnect. Authentication succeeded and I received a token from Azure.

In later methods I need to pass the token as parameter, so now I store it in session variable, but this expires earlier and results in an empty variable.

Now I'm trying to acquire a token from Azure with ADAL.

```
 string userObjectId = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ToString() == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")?.Value;
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"], new TokenCache());
 ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"], "client_secret"); 
 var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"], credential).Result.AccessToken;
```

This results in an error:

> ```
> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50105: Application > 
> '4337e286-7b84-4377-8843-82ea9504606b' is not assigned to a role for the application '4337e286-7b84-4377-8843-82ea9504606b'}
> ```

For other apps, it is set up with another app which has permissions for the resource, but I don't want to depend on another app to get the token.

Anyone an idea?

**EDIT**

I've followed the suggestion of @Jean-MarcPrieur, but on the line

```
var accounts = await application.GetAccountsAsync();
```

it returns no accounts which results in an empty result and no accessToken.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to use the [client credentials flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) (which requires your app to register permissions to call the Web API you want to call - tenant admin permissions).

If you want to access resources in the name of the user, you need to acquire a token for your app to call the API in the name of the signed-in user.
See for instance this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph which signs-in an user and calls the graph
It's an ASP.NET Core sample using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint (the latest technos). If you have other constraints, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You can reuse the powershell app id to get around the requirement for registration.

Comment: @Swend, this bad practice. Every app should have their own app registration.

Comment: @Jean-MarcPrieur Can this also be used in .NET?

Comment: @NiAu: I don't understand your question. What can be used in .NET? I provided .NET links?